# Implicit conversion to struct executes against Nullable<struct>

Tags: c#, null, nullable, implicit-conversion

Given a class with an implicit conversion operator to a `Guid`:

```
class MyId
{
    private readonly Guid innerGuid;

    public MyId(Guid innerGuid)
    {
        this.innerGuid = innerGuid;
    }

    public static implicit operator Guid(MyId id)
    {
        return id.innerGuid;
    }
}
```

When assigning to a `Nullable<Guid>`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyId someId = null;
        Guid? optionalId = someId;
        Console.WriteLine("optionalId = " + (optionalId.HasValue ? optionalId.Value.ToString() : "NULL"));
    }
```

I would expect the null reference to simply propagate across from `someId` to `optionalId`. ie. get the console output:

> optionalId = NULL

However the compiler seems to take precedence on the Nullable's inner Guid type, and it attempts to execute the implicit conversion, which throws a NRE as the `id` parameter is obviously null.

Is this a bug or by design?

It can be fixed with a null coalescing operator and explicit null value:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyId someId = null;
        Guid? optionalId = someId ?? (Guid?) null;
        Console.WriteLine("optionalId = " + (optionalId.HasValue ? optionalId.Value.ToString() : "NULL"));
    }
```

But that seems very weird. Resharper even fades it out, implying its unnecessary and states:

> '??' right operand is always null

Comment: Have you tried `optionalId = (MyId)null` see if it throws or not. Currently null casted to guid obviously does not invoke your implicit operator which takes MyId

Comment: IMHO, what you describe is correct behavior. It is correctly executing the implicit operator. You can fix it by adding an implicit operator to a Nullable<Guid> and using the null coalescing operator ?? in that function. Alternatively, change the implicit operator you have to return a Nullable<Guid>.  It should probably work for both Guid and Nullable<Guid>;

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Yes, adding an implicit operator for the `Nullable<Guid>` overload does fix this case. Unfortunately my real case is not so simple (a generic base class `Identity<TId>`, which can use Guid,  int, string, etc. Adding an implicit conversion to `Nullable<TId>` means I have to give `TId` a struct constraint, which means I can no longer use Identity<string>)

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz But I guess my point is, the left hand side is of type `Guid?`, the right hand side is `MyId`. I have an implicit conversion from `MyId` -> `Guid`, but not `MyId` -> `Guid?`, so why should it run the non-nullable conversion, when copying the null ref is a completely valid operation?

Comment: @Tyson, true about Identity<string> but you could use Identity<StringWrapper> where StringWrapper is a struct containing a string. Sucky I know.

Comment: @ Tyson, because you've a variable of type MyId, not of Guid? and you're assigning that variable to a Guid? and the MyId type has an IMPLICIT conversion operator. If you made it EXPLICIT then the compiler would probably complain about no conversion. What exactly would you expect to happen by assigning a null Foo class instance to a Guid? variable? Do you really expect that to be meaningful?

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz ***facepalm***. You're right. Not sure where my brain was going with that line of reasoning. Thanks!! If you add that explanation as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Tyson, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you've a variable of type MyId, not of Guid? and you're assigning that variable to a Guid? and the MyId type has an IMPLICIT conversion operator. If you made it EXPLICIT then the compiler would probably complain about no conversion. What exactly would you expect to happen by assigning a null Foo class instance to a Guid? variable? Do you really expect that to be meaningful? –